# What is the impact on database source systems doing queries from a trino cluster?

Tags: amazon-athena, presto, trino

I´ve been doing some POCS with trino (aka presto).
I am very happy with the performance even with small trino clusters. Mostly my pocs are against data lakes doing replication source data from **operational critical databases.**
But my question is :

**What is the impact on database source systems doing queries from a trino cluster?**

I am still missing some parts of the internal architecture of trino on **how interacts a trino query against the source database.**